# Power Point Presentaion in IE10

Tags: html, powerpoint, internet-explorer-10, openoffice-impress

I use MS PowerPoint tool to publish ppt as html.
The html shows fine in IE8, but in the case of IE10 its is not usable.

I am looking for Slideshow with PowerPoint for IE10.

I use Open Office to convert my PPT to HTML but slideshow option missing when impress convert to HTML which is avalable in MS office to view fullscreen presentation.

Comment: IE10 doesn't support that feature. You should look for a way to force IE10 to read the site in compatibility mode.

Comment: Any other way to create ppt to HTML for IE10.\